# im trying to get a variable from my main page to the admin panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an admin panel and I've been trying to pass variables from the main page to the admin panel, the main page is not located in the same folder, not sure if that's something that interrupts it but here's the point I found that you can do 
**`localStorage.setItem(something,value)`** i tried to make the input in my admin panel the same in as in my main page, that's my code
main page

```
<ul id="aidi" style="display: inline-block;"> <!-- Don't change -->
            <li style="margin-left: 40px;">
            <input value="Ziggs" id="1st" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px;" disabled="yes"> <!-- 1st Champion's name -->
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: -120px;"> <!-- 2nd Champion's name -->
            <input value="thresh" id="2nd" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px;" disabled="yes">
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: -120px;"> <!-- 3rd Champion's name -->
            <input value="darius" id="3rd" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px;" disabled="yes">
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: -120px;"> <!-- 4th Champion's name -->
            <input value="lux" id="4th" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px;" disabled="yes">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="aidi2"> <!-- Dates -->
            <li style="margin-left: 55px;" > <!-- 1st Champion's date -->
                Dec 8,2016
            </li> 
            <li style="margin-left: 235px;"> <!-- 2nd Champion's date -->
             Dec 6,2016
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 230px;"> <!-- 3rd Champion's date -->
             Dec 4,2016
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 225px;"> <!-- 4th Champion's date -->
            Dec 3,2016
            </li>
        </ul> <!-- Don't change -->
```

getting the variables code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $first = $('#1st').val();
    $second = $('#2nd').val();
    $third = $('#3rd').val();
    $forth = $('#4th').val();
    localStorage.setItem('1st' , $first);
    localStorage.setItem('2nd' , $second);
    localStorage.setItem('3rd' , $third);
    localStorage.setItem('4th' , $forth);

});
```

trying to get the variables in my admin panel **jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var first = $('1st');
var second = $('2nd');
var third = $('3rd');
var forth = $('4th');
$('#firstchamp').val() = localStorage.getItem("1st");
$('#secondchamp').val() = localStorage.getItem("2nd");
$('#thirdchamp').val() = localStorage.getItem("3rd");
$('#forthchamp').val() = localStorage.getItem("4th");

});
```

admin panel code:

```
<div id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container" id="homepagecon">
        <h1 id="homepage">Home Page</h1>
            <div class="champs"><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Darius_4.jpg"><input id="firstchamp" value="" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="champs"><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Darius_1.jpg"><input id="secondchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="champs"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/15/27/a9/1527a98dcc96c4fead214e15737d8fa9.jpg"><input id="thirdchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="champs"><img src="http://img15.deviantart.net/5477/i/2016/158/5/3/darius_by_siakim-da5cc7z.jpg"><input id="forthchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the way your setting the values in the admin panel, the `.val()` function is misused, you need to use it as following (and BTW the first four statements are not needed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("1st"));
    $('#secondchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("2nd"));
    $('#thirdchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("3rd"));
    $('#forthchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("4th"));
});
```

Comment: now it says `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I think this is unrelated to this piece of code, it see,s that your back-end has been updated

Comment: the input in my admin panel doesn't change to the value of the input in my main page tho, any ideas why? im checking if i move it to the same folder if it'll work sec

Comment: Are you sure which order the scripts are run in?

Comment: nope, how do i check the order, they're 2 different files

Comment: After loading your page in the browser, view the page's source, and check which script is appearing top-most. Or you can put breakpoints in the sources of your page and check which hits first

Comment: You're welcome, kindly mark this as the correct answer for future references.

Answer (score 3):

Set val() function is not used properly please try below code to set value please find [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for more information

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var first = $('1st');
    var second = $('2nd');
    var third = $('3rd');
    var forth = $('4th');
    $('#firstchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("1st"));
    $('#secondchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("2nd"));
    $('#thirdchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("3rd"));
    $('#forthchamp').val(localStorage.getItem("4th"));

});
```

Comment: @GuySudai completely my pleasure you are always welcome ... :-)